# How to insert backslash before a group with regex re.sub() in python

Tags: python, json, regex, escaping, python-re

I have a text string that I want to convert to JSON, like:

```
{text1: text2}
```

however text2 is filled with illegal characters: "{[]},
so it won't be parsed correctly.

I would like to escape each illegal character by inserting a backslash before it, but I can't get it to work.

The closest I can get is :

```
In [6]: re.sub('([\[\]\{\},"]{1})', r'\\\1', 'abc[def') 
Out[6]: 'abc\\[def'
```

But this inserts two backslashes instead of one... I can't get it to insert one.

On second though, perhaps the problem is with my json.loads()?
Here's an example:

```
In [41]: z
Out[41]: '{"abc": "sdfd\\[sfsdfdf"}'
In [42]: print(z)
Out[42]: {"abc": "sdfd\[sfsdfdf"}
```

As you can see by the difference between z and print(z), the backslash is properly escaped. But when I execute

```
json.loads(z)
```

I still get the Invalid escape error on the backslash.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just use `re.escape` function and 2 backslashes is just print issue

Comment: It doesn't insert 2 backslashes. To see this, call `print()` on the value you get back from `re.sub()`.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be just a print issue, when I parse it into json with json.load it gets stuck on the double backslash.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to escape brackets for [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). JSON expects a unicode character number or `"`, `\` and widespaces. The problem is rather how Python handles escape sequences in strings. Just feed it as raw string to `json.loads()`:

```py
import json

json.loads(r'{"abc": "abc[def"}')
json.loads(r'{"abc": "ab\\cd\"e\tf"}')
json.loads('{"abc": "abc'+ re.escape('abc\def') +'def"}')
```

would print:

> {'abc': 'abc[def'}
> {'abc': 'ab\cd"e\tf'}
> {'abc': 'abcabc\defdef'}

So you can keep your code but you need to escape the right characters:

```py
import json
import re

json.loads(r'{"abc": "' + re.sub(r'\\', r'\\\\', 'abc\def') + '"}')
```

> {'abc': 'abc\def'}